# Line between 2 points in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a two-dimesional array like this:

```bat
%v[0][0]%%v[0][1]%%v[0][2]%%v[0][3]% ........

%v[1][0]%%v[1][1]%%v[1][2]%%v[1][3]% .........
```

---

and 4 variables that retain the coordinates of 2 points (A and B) in the array:
`xa`, `ya`, `xb`, `yb`

How would I draw a pixel line (by setting values in the array to a character) between the 2 points in batch script, even if the points are on different lines?

I am working on a map editor for a  pure batch 2D shooter game engine.

I have a function that ads points on the given coordinates, one for squares and one for lines that only works when the ends of the line(the given points) have the same `X` value or the same `Y` value. For this I use:

```bat
for /L %%i in (%xa%,1,%xb%) do set v[%coord_ya%][%%i]=*
```

Now I need a piece of code that draws a `#` line between 2 points that are on different axis. If it would have been done in a pixel art programm it would look like this:

[image]

where the green dots are the given points (with coordinates: `A(1,1)` and `B(4,7)`) and the yellow dots represent what I need to draw with `#`.

Comment: We have some topics about this on DosTips.com.  Trying to find them for you. Feel free to post your question on the forums over there.  My Google Foo is failing me today.  There is a lot of guys who do graphics stuff on that forum.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to use as base

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "xMax=75"
    set "yMax=23"

    call :clearBoard
    call :drawLine 1 23 75 2 *
    call :drawLine 1 1 75 23 #
    call :drawLine 1 12 75 12 -
    call :drawLine 39 1 39 23 "|"
    call :drawLine 1 16 60 2 "."
    call :drawLine 1 6 23 20 :
    call :drawLine 1 1 4 7 @
    call :dumpBoard
    goto :eof


:clearBoard 
    for /l %%x in (0 1 %xMax%) do for /l %%y in (0 1 %yMax%) do set "v[%%x][%%y]= "
    goto :eof

:drawLine xa ya xb yb char
    rem Retrive arguments
    set "xa=%1"
    set "ya=%2"
    set "xb=%3"
    set "yb=%4"
    set "char=%~5"

    rem Calulate difference between coordinates start/end and its absolute values
    set /a "dx=xb-xa", "dy=yb-ya", "adx=(dx>>31|1)*dx", "ady=(dy>>31|1)*dy"

    rem Not having decimals, from here we will handle all coordinates 
    rem multiplied by 1000 and later divide to determine real coordinate

    rem For the axis with the greater difference we will move 1 cell in each step 
    rem and increment the other coordinate proportinally
    if %adx% gtr %ady% (
        set /a "ix=1000*(dx>>31|1)", "iy=dy*1000/adx", "dMax=adx"
    ) else (
        set /a "iy=1000*(dy>>31|1)", "ix=dx*1000/ady", "dMax=ady"
    )

    rem just for debugging
    if defined debug (
        for %%a in ( xa ya xb yb dx dy adx ady ix iy dMax x y ) do echo %%a = !%%a!
        pause
    )

    rem For each step in what ever axis selected
    for /l %%d in (0 1 %dMax%) do (
        rem Determine board coordinates where to draw
        set /a "vx=(xa*1000+ix*%%d)/1000", "vy=(ya*1000+iy*%%d)/1000"
        rem "Draw" point in board
        set "v[!vx!][!vy!]=%char%"
    )
    goto :eof

:dumpBoard    
    cls
    for /l %%y in (0 1 %yMax%) do (
        set "line[%%y]="
        for /l %%x in (0 1 %xMax%) do set "line[%%y]=!line[%%y]!!v[%%x][%%y]!"
    )
    echo ...:0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
    echo ...:0123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789   
    for /l %%y in (0 1 %yMax%) do (
        set /a "l=1000+%%y"
        echo(!l:~-3!:!line[%%y]!
    )
    goto :eof
```

Output:

```
...:0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
...:0123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789
000:
001: @###                                  |
002: @   ###                               |                .....           ****
003:  @     ####                           |            ....             ***
004:  @         ###                        |        ....             ****
005:   @           ###                     |    ....              ***
006: ::@              ####                 .....              ****
007:   :@                 ###          ....|               ***
008:     :                   ###   ....    |           ****
009:      ::                   ....#       |       ****
010:        :              ....     ###    |    ***
011:         ::       .....            ####|****
012: ----------::-....---------------------|------------------------------------
013:          ...:                   ****  |  ###
014:      ....    ::              ***      |     ####
015:  ....          :         ****         |         ###
016: .               ::    ***             |            ###
017:                   :***                |               ####
018:                *** ::                 |                   ###
019:            ****      ::               |                      ###
020:         ***                           |                         ####
021:     ****                              |                             ###
022:  ***                                  |                                ####
023: *                                     |
```

This code determines in which axis there is a greater distance. For each point along this greater axis distance a character will be placed in the board. The second coordinate in the shorter distance axis is computed by dividing the distance in this axis between the number of points we will be placing along the greater axis.

As batch file arithmetics does not handle decimals, all operations are done on values multiplied by 1000. Once we need to move to real coordinates the values are divided by 1000.